Are windows expected to be deallocated when they are closed in Mac Catalyst apps?
I have an iOS app that I'm working to enable Mac Catalyst support for. I have multi-window support implemented via the UISceneSession API. I'm finding that when I open and then close secondary windows, the root view controller of the window isn't always deallocated (meaning I don't get a call to dealloc - yes, this is mostly in Objective-C).
I've been disabling parts of the view controller in question to try to narrow down what's going on, and am getting inconsistent results. I can comment out a bit of code and run the app, and I get dealloc on close. I uncomment it and try again, and no dealloc. Then I comment it out again and run it, and no dealloc!
At this point I feel I should sanity-check my assumptions: should I expect that when I close a window in a Mac Catalyst app, it and its root view controller should always be deallocated? Or is the system allowed to keep it around sometimes, and I should do cleanup somewhere like sceneWillDisconnect? I have noticed that the scene delegate does always get deallocated.

Yes, in general you should expect the root view controller of a closed window to be deallocated immediately. If it isn't, you likely have a bug in your code causing a reference cycle. I just verified this with my own Mac Catalyst app. It supports 3 different scenes with 3 different root view controllers. Closing a given window resulted in the root view controller being deallocated immediately.
